# Specifying a function type signature in a where clause

Tags: haskell, ghc, recursion-schemes, catamorphism

The following function implements the good old *filter* function from lists
by using the [recursion-schemes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes) library.

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable 

catafilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] 
catafilter p = cata alg 
  where
    -- alg :: ListF a [a] -> [a]
    alg  Nil  =  []
    alg  (Cons x xs) = if (p x) then x : xs else xs
```

It compiles and a short test like `catafilter odd [1,2,3,4]` is successful.
However, if I uncomment the type signature for `alg` I get the following error:

```
src/cata.hs:8:30: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘a1’
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          alg :: forall a1. ListF a1 [a1] -> [a1]
        at src/cata.hs:6:5-29
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          catafilter :: forall a. (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
        at src/cata.hs:3:1-39
    • In the first argument of ‘p’, namely ‘x’
      In the expression: (p x)
      In the expression: if (p x) then x : xs else xs
    • Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [a1] (bound at src/cata.hs:8:18)
        x :: a1 (bound at src/cata.hs:8:16)
        alg :: ListF a1 [a1] -> [a1] (bound at src/cata.hs:7:5)
        p :: a -> Bool (bound at src/cata.hs:4:12)
        catafilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] (bound at src/cata.hs:4:1)
  |
8 |     alg  (Cons x xs) = if (p x) then x : xs else xs
  |                              ^
```

The answer to the SO question [type-signature-in-a-where-clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928884/type-signature-in-a-where-clause)
suggests to use the *ScopedTypeVariables* extension. 
The comment in the last answer to [why-is-it-so-uncommon-to-use-type-signatures-in-where-clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609936/why-is-it-so-uncommon-to-use-type-signatures-in-where-clauses)
suggests to use a *forall* quantification.

So I added:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
```

at the top of my module and tried different type signatures for *alg* like: 
`alg :: forall a. ListF a [a] -> [a]` or 
`alg :: forall b. ListF b [b] -> [b]` or adding a *forall* to the *catalist* type signature. Nothing compiled!

Question: Why I'm not able to specify a type signature for *alg*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without extensions, the original uncommented code

```
catafilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] 
catafilter p = cata alg 
  where
    alg :: ListF a [a] -> [a]
    alg  Nil  =  []
    alg  (Cons x xs) = if (p x) then x : xs else xs
```

is equivalent, after enabling `ScopedTypeVariables`, to explicitly quantifying all the type variables, as follows:

```
catafilter :: forall a. (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] 
catafilter p = cata alg 
  where
    alg :: forall a. ListF a [a] -> [a]
    alg  Nil  =  []
    alg  (Cons x xs) = if (p x) then x : xs else xs
```

This in turn is equivalent to (by alpha converting the quantified variables)

```
catafilter :: forall a. (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] 
catafilter p = cata alg 
  where
    alg :: forall b. ListF b [b] -> [b]
    alg  Nil  =  []
    alg  (Cons x xs) = if (p x) then x : xs else xs
```

and this triggers a type error since `p` wants an `a` argument, but `p x` passes a `b` argument.

The point is, with the extension enabled, a function starting with `forall b. ...` is promising that it can work with any choice of `b`. This promise is too strong for `alg`, which only works on the same `a` of `catafilter`.

So, the solution is the following. The type of `catafilter` can promise to work with any `a` its caller might choose: we can add `forall a.` there.
Instead, `alg` must promise only to work with the same `a` of `catafilter`, so we reuse the type variable `a` without adding another `forall`.

```
catafilter :: forall a. (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] 
catafilter p = cata alg 
  where
    alg :: ListF a [a] -> [a]
    alg  Nil  =  []
    alg  (Cons x xs) = if (p x) then x : xs else xs
```

this compiles since `ScopedTypeVariables` sees that `a` is in scope, and does not add an implicit `forall` in `alg` (as it would happen without th extension).

Summary:

- Without `ScopedTypeVariables`, every type annotation has its own implicit `forall ...` on top, quantifying all the variables. No annotation can refer to variables of other annotations (you can reuse the same name, but it is not considered the same variable).
- With `ScopedTypeVariables`, the definition `foo :: forall t. T t u ; foo = def` is handled as follows:

  - the type variable `t` is universally quantified and brought in scope when type checking `def`: type annotations in `def` can refer to `t`
  - the type variable `u`, if currently in scope, refers to the externally defined `u`
  - the type variable `u`, if not in scope, is universally quantified but not brought in scope when type checking `def` (for compatibility, here we follow the same behavior without the extension)

Answer (score 5):

This works

```
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable 

catafilter :: forall a. (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] 
catafilter p = cata alg
  where
    alg :: ListF a [a] -> [a]
    alg  Nil  =  []
    alg  (Cons x xs) = if (p x) then x : xs else xs
```

---

If you omit the `forall`, these are completely different `a`s (even though syntactically they are the same).

Because of implicit quantification, your uncommented version is taken to be

```
catafilter :: forall a. (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] 
catafilter p = cata alg
  where
    alg :: forall a1. ListF a1 [a1] -> [a1]
    alg  Nil  =  []
    alg  (Cons x xs) = if (p x) then x : xs else xs
```

This explains your error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘a1’
```

The predicate (`p :: a -> Bool`) expects an argument of type `a` but it was given `x :: a1` from `Cons x xs :: ListF a1 [a1]`!

See if the explicitly quantified version makes sense given the bindings from the error message:

```
xs         :: [a1] 
x          :: a1
alg        :: ListF a1 [a1] -> [a1] 
p          :: a -> Bool 
catafilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: Try replacing `p x` with `undefined`. Does the error go away? Why/why not? — Pass the predicate explicitly to `alg :: forall a1. (a1 -> Bool) -> ListF a1 [a1] -> [a1]` with `catafilter = cata . alg`. Which `forall`s can you remove? Can you freely rename your type variables or not?

Answer (score 1):

This works, and avoids all that counter-intuitive mucking around with `forall`s

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable 

catafilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] 
catafilter p = cata alg 
  where
    -- alg :: ListF a [a] -> [a]
    alg  (Nil :: ListF aa [aa])  =  [] :: [aa]
    alg  (Cons x xs) = if (p x) then x : xs else xs
```

On the `alg Nil` equation I could actually use tyvar `a`: I used `aa` merely to show they're distinct bindings. Because `aa` appears on a pattern, the compiler unifies it with `a` from the signature for `catafilter`.

You could also/instead put the type annotations on the `alg Cons` equation.

I understand @Jogger's confusion as to why ghc is so fussy about the position of the `forall`; and the nervousness that a `forall` perhaps indicates `RankNTypes`.

Comment: Thanks for your additional answer! For me it was important to have a normal type signature of the function `alg` as a compiler  checkable signature and not only as a comment. A comment may be wrong. And thanks to the answers of chi and Icland_jack I now understand _forall_

Comment: I left the comment in from your O.P. It is the two type annotations that are doing the work, and they _are_ checked by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `alg` depends on an external `p`, so `alg`'s type can't be simply polymorphic.

One simple way around it is to make it independent of any external entities by passing them in as the function arguments, so that the function can have its simply polymorphic type as expected:

```
catafilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
catafilter = cata . alg
  where
    alg :: (b -> Bool) -> ListF b [b] -> [b]
    alg p Nil  =  []
    alg p (Cons x xs)  =  if (p x) then x : xs else xs
```

This doesn't need any language extensions.